# Using GUI to add an object to an arraylist

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

this is the related block of the program...

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
       String command = event.getActionCommand();
       if(command.equals("Add Book"))
       {
           addBook();
       }
       if(command.equals("Clear"))
       {
           clear();
       }
   }

   /**
    * Add a Book to the arraylist LoanItem
    */
   public void addBook(String theISBN, String theTitle, String thePublisher)
   {
      Book theBook = new Book(theISBN, theTitle, thePublisher);
      LoanItems.add(theBook);
```

it comes up as error method addbook in class library cannot be applied to given types.
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `addBook()`, but didn't pass any of the parameters that you specified for it. You need to get the information that you are supposed to pass and then supply it to the call:

```
if ("clear".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
    addBook(String, String, String);
}
```